# Does UIView spring animations use the easing curve options?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

In [the examples](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-animate-views-with-spring-damping-using-animatewithduration) I can [find online](https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/a-look-at-uiview-animation-curves-part-1-191d9e6de0ab), developers seem to always provide a easing curve to a spring animation:

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 1,
    delay: 0,
    usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
    initialSpringVelocity: 5,
    options: .curveEaseInOut,
    animations: {
        // some changes
    }
)
```

I tried creating an animation with a linear curve:

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 1,
    delay: 0,
    usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
    initialSpringVelocity: 5,
    options: .curveLinear,
    animations: {
        // some changes
    }
)
```

However, it produces the same exact same animation. It seems like the easing option is not used at all.

Here's a sample I made, the yellow rectangle uses `.curveEaseInOut`, the green one `.curveLinear`.

[image: animation example]

Am I missing something or should the easing just not be passed with using spring animations?

You can find the [code for the sample here](https://github.com/teameh/SwiftCodeSamples/blob/cfca4d6827b1dc2cd19479412f582b57e56c9882/CodeSamples/Controllers/AnimatingConstraintsVC.swift#L113).

Comment: In the shared code, you are applying both animations at the same time. Can you fix that first?

Comment: Well they need to be applied at the same time to visually see the difference in animation right?